# Insert New Row with Auto Incremental ID in Oracle

Tags: oracle, insert, oracleforms

I use oracle forms builder, I have in database table `XXCR_MAINT_HDRS` that contains `maintenaceNO` number(15), and I have SEQUENCE `INV_HDR_NO_S`,  I have to write new_form_instance trigger to system generate `maintenanceNO` when i compile and run oracle forms , I wrote this code

```
BEFORE INSERT ON XXCR_MAINT_HDRS
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (NEW.TRX_NUM IS NULL)
BEGIN
  select INV_HDR_NO_S.NEXTVAL
   INTO :NEW.TRX_NUM from dual;
END;
```

and this code

```
BEFORE INSERT ON XXCR_MAINT_HDRS
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
  select INV_HDR_NO_S_ID.NEXTVAL
   INTO :NEW.ID from dual;
END;
```

and for both code I have this

> error 103 at line encountered the symbole insert when expecting :=@%

Comment: which database you are using. Where is `CREATE` Keyword

Comment: You are missing the `create trigger` part for your trigger

Answer (score 0):

You can't select Into the row variable you need to use an intertim variable 
The code needs to look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER XXCR_MAINT_HDRS_TRG
BEFORE INSERT ON XXCR_MAINT_HDRS
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL)
DECLARE
  v_id XXCR_MAINT_HDRS.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN

   select INV_HDR_NO_S_ID.NEXTVAL INTO v_id from dual;
  :new.ID := v_id;
END XXCR_MAINT_HDRS_TRG;
```

**Oracle 12 addition**

another way to implement this is a new feature that was introduced at oracle 12 that enables sequences to be used as identity columns:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE t1_seq;

CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id          NUMBER DEFAULT t1_seq.NEXTVAL,
  description VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

For more information take a look at those links:

http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1.php

http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/default-values-for-table-columns-enhancements-12cr1.php

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a database trigger if you use this syntax.
So if you use asafm example and create this database trigger then it will fill in the number.

If you want to use a trigger in oracle forms to fill in the number you should create a pre-insert trigger. Or if you want the value to be there when you create the record you should use a when-create-record trigger. The code for this trigger will be the following:

```
select INV_HDR_NO_S.NEXTVAL
into :BLOCK_NAME.TRX_NUM from dual;
```